# PHP Call of undefined function from included file

Tags: php, url, ftp, remote-access

I'm trying to use fucntion that defined in remote file. I add this file like this:

```
require_once 'http://x.x.x.x:port/file_name.php';  
// file is located at ftp-server
```

And I'm getting error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function func_name() in php_file.php

I used `CURL function` to check if file exist and it returned code 200 that means that file exists. Help please.

**upd1**. `ini_get('allow_url_include')` returned me 1.

**upd2**. I've tried to call this function within the file itself it works fine

Comment: Is the function `func_name()` defined in php_file.php?

Comment: The error message is from within the file. Can you edit the content of "php_file.php"?

Comment: Am I looking so stupid? Sure it is

Comment: @Albin I've tried to call this function within the file itself it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that you are getting the raw (not interpreted by the remote server) php file? Get the file using `curl` and print it (or simply put included file's url into browser) or change remote file's extension to e.g. 'txt' to prevent it for being interpreted.

By the way: including remote files is probably not the most secure thing in the world.

Comment: Thanks. Can u advice me what to do if I need to execute function on remote server?

Comment: If your remote server supports PHP, your included file executes when You try to get it by using `require_once` (and it probably returns empty page). Put the url in your web browser and see if you are getting blank page (so the file was already executed) or php code (file was not executed on remote server). Also - as I said - _"change remote file's extension to e.g. 'txt' to prevent it for being interpreted"_.

Also mind the error message - is it mentioning your local or remote file?

Comment: Hah)) Seems that this is the solution

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by setting allow_url_include to on on php.ini.

Look at this answer :
[Can't include file on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498885/cant-include-file-on-remote-server)

Comment: I think the file is being included going by the error message. Also, this would be better as a comment and then flag as a duplicate if you think it is.